# Custom 400 redirect based on MVC Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Is there a way to override the default 400 redirect (set in web.config) on a per-controller basis?

Say I have an Admin controller and an Account controller, each has a custom AuthorizeAttribute. There are two different login forms, and I need the admin controller to redirect to it's when AdminAuthorize attribute is false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could always implement your own [authorization attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute.aspx):

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method | AttributeTargets.Class, Inherited = true, AllowMultiple = true)]
public class CustomAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        var controllerName = filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.ControllerName;
        var actionName = filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ActionName;
        // TODO: Now that you know the controller name and the action name
        // act accordingly or call the base method
    }
}
```